# Can I control multiple instances of movieclips in a loaded swf at once?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, loader, movieclip

I am loading an swf created in flash professional cs5 via the loader class into a flex 4.1 application. The flash file contains multiple movieclips that are exported for actionscript and those movieclips exist in many instances throughout the movie.

Iterating through everything, comparing class types seems to be the most easy but also the most redundant way to solve this. Is there any way of using the class name as a kind of global selector to access the clips?

I could also make the sub-clips in the flash listen for an event on which they perform an action, but I am not really sure what might be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess typing it out did the trick. i used the event solution:

in the root timeline i placed a function like this:

```
function cause():void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event("do stuff",true));
}
```

and in the library clip's main timeline goes:

```
DisplayObject(root).addEventListener("do stuff", function (e:Event=null) {
    ... whatever ...         
});
```

this is dirty but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these, I find that a good way to solve the problem is to create a statically accessable class that manages instances of other classes that are registered with it on instantiation.  As an example...

```
public class GlobalStopper{
    private static var clips:Array = [];
    public static function add(mc:MovieClip):void{
        clips.push(mc);
    }
    public static function stop():void{
        var mc:MovieClip;
        for(var i:int = 0, ilen:int = clips.length ; i < ilen ; i++){
            mc = clips[i] as MovieClip;
            if (mc) mc.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class GloballyStoppableMovieClip extends MovieClip{

    public function GloballyStoppableMovieClip(){
        GlobalStopper.add(this);
    }

}
```

Any and all instances of GloballyStoppableMovieClip are instantly registered with the GlobalStopper, so calling

```
GlobalStopper.stop();
```

...will stop all registered movieclips.

You can add in any other functions you want.  Furthermore, instead of having add accept MovieClip instances,  you could have it accept IStoppable or IPlayable objects that implement public functions stop() and play() that your movieclip subclass (or non-movieclip object that also might need to stop and play!) then implements.

But as for jQuery-like selectors?  Not really the way I'd handle this particular issue.

Comment: also a nice approach! thanks, i'll give that a thought as well!